# Designing a simple book recommendation system in python?

Tags: python, django, recommendation-engine

I have been designing a simple recommendation system for books. So on signup I will ask users to choose their favorite genres. Each book will also have a genre plus each genre will have a weight.

Suppose **Book** Model has a field **Genre_Score**(a text field which is json-formatted dictionary with key as the genre and value as the weight) something like

```
{"Thriller":5, "Adventure":59,"Biography":21}
```

Similarly every **User** Model will have Genre_Score like

```
{"Thriller":1, "Adventure":1,"Biography":2}
```

Now after each book is complete I ask the user to answer if he liked or not the book and accordingly update the **Genre_Score** of that book and user. 
Is using the above (json-formatted text field) Data-structure a good approach? Will the **querying** will be very expensive as for every user I will have to generate a **Feed** matching his Genre_score and Books' genre scores? Or should I take a different approach all-together ?

Comment: are you using PostgreSQL? you know there's no DictField built in to Django right?   another approach would be to have a `Genre` model and a ManyToMany from `Book` to `Genre` with the score stored on the through model

Comment: text field I meant which is JSON formatted. Sorry for the confusion. Yes the other approach you mentioned is also what I am thinking will that be better than this approach ?

Comment: if you store JSON text in a text field you're not going to be able to query for specific values in the dict

Comment: I would start with the many-to-many models approach and get it working that way first, later on you will be able to see if any queries are too slow ...and knowing which ones you will have a better idea what, if anything, needs to be optimised

Comment: So a Genre model with m2m relationship with Book/User Model. Genre Model will contains the fields genre_name , genre_score ? Will genre_score be an issue? Match-making will still be tough i.e creating feed for a particular user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you model it like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=255)


class BookGenre(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book')
    genre = models.ForeignKey('Genre')
    score = models.IntegerField()


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # etc...
    genres = models.ManyToManyField('Genre', through=BookGenre)


class UserGenre(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    genre = models.ForeignKey('Genre')
    score = models.IntegerField()


class User(AbstractUser):
    genres = models.ManyToManyField('Genre', through=UserGenre)
```

See the docs here for more details, such as how to query against the score etc:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: excellent. But why 2 different models for BookGenre and UserGenre and score is in them ? I was thinking of a simply a another model Genre with title and score ? What advantage this gives?

Comment: if you put the score in the `Genre` model then a genre can only have one score for all books and users... in the examples you gave it seemed you wanted each book to be able to have it's own score for each genre (makes sense) and same for users

Comment: Thanks . Let me try this and get back .

Comment: some issues coming the migrations. When to write model name in foreign key/m2m fields in quotes and when without quotes. You write every time with quotes except in `through=` ?

Comment: I think they could all be written with quotes... you are required to use quotes when the model you want hasn't been defined yet (i.e. it's defined later in the same file) but above they are not needed.  if the models are in different apps then you should use quotes with a path like `genres = models.ManyToManyField('myotherapp.Genre', through='UserGenre')`

Comment: this error is coming `ValueError: Cannot alter field book.Book.genres into book.Book.genres - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields`

Comment: yes you're going to have to write the migration manually since it sounds like you already had a `genres` field on your `Book` model... just write a schema migration to first drop the `genres` field... then you can do an `--auto` migration to add the new m2m field

Comment: (or do them both in one hand-written schema migration)